# Testing Rails Controller with Session

Tags: session, testing, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, controller

In my app i've got a session controller. Now i want to test the users controller which is only accessible if one is logged in.

My problem is how can i fake the session. i've already tried a lot so i hope you can help me now:

The application controller:

```
   helper_method :current_user
   def authenticate_user
     current_user
     if @current_user
       return true
     else
       redirect_to(:controller => 'sessions', :action => 'new')
       return false
     end
   end

   private
     def current_user
     @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
   end
```

The Users Controller has:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user
```

The Controller Test:

```
describe "GET index" do
  it "assigns all users as @users" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    @request.session[:user_id] = user.id
    get 'users'
    expect(@users.size).to eq(1)
  end
end
```

I've also tried `session[:user_id] = user.id` and debugging (after the get request):

- save_and_open_page let me see the login page.
- `@current_user` is always nil
- `User.find(session[:user_id])` returns the correct user

Comment: For reference, this is no longer possible in rails 5.

Comment: @RobinClowers What do you do for Rails 5 then?

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796129/unable-to-set-session-hash-in-rails-5-controller-test/43563901#43563901

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `controller` instead of `@request`:

```
user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
controller.session[:user_id] = user.id
get 'users'
expect(@users.size).to eq(1)
```

Also do you have `@users` variable defined in test?  Probably it should be `expect(User.count).to eq(1)`