# Unable to set session hash in Rails 5 controller test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

According to the [Rails Edge Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#functional-tests-for-your-controllers) all ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest HTTP requests take optional named keyword arguments:

`get post_url, params: { id: 12 }, session: { user_id: 5 }`

Great. Now, I've got the following code in a controller test:

```
test 'should redirect from login page if user is logged in' do
  get '/login', session: { user_id: users(:stephen).id }
  assert_redirected_to root_url, 'Expected redirect to root'
end
```

And when I run it, my test **fails** and I see the following deprecation warning:

```
ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest HTTP request methods will accept only
the following keyword arguments in future Rails versions:
params, headers, env, xhr
```

So obviously it's rails is not letting me pass a keyword argument named **session**.

Furthermore, both of the old methods of setting the session in a functional test no longer work either:

```
test "some thing" do
  session[:user_id] = users(:stephen).id
  # etc
end
```

> NoMethodError: undefined method `session' for nil:NilClass

And this fails too:

```
test "some thing" do
  get '/login', nil, nil, { user_id: users(:stephen).id }
  # etc
end
```

The session hash is just ignored and the deprecation warning about rails only accepting 4 different named arguments appears.

Is anyone else having this sort of trouble with Rails 5.rc1?

Comment: According to the example `get post_url, params: { id: 12 }, session: { user_id: 5 }` the second argument is *params*, `get '/login', session: { user_id: users(:stephen).id }` but you pass the *session*, have you tried `get '/login', params: {}, session: { user_id: users(:stephen).id }` ?

Comment: @Зелёный the arguments are all entirely optional, and order is unimportant, and yes I did try your idea, and it doesn't fix the issue

Comment: That's weird, because that works smoothly in my tests

Comment: I'll start from scratch and see if I've done something dumb elsewhere in my code.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the error comes from the test that you pasted in the question? The error should be shown only when calling the test [the old way](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb#L462), i.e. using positional parameters instead of hash.

Comment: @BoraMa I fixed the issue temporarily using some things I found in the link your posted. Basically there is a rails bug, and I posted an answer below. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Rails 5 it is no longer possible to access session in controller tests: http://blog.napcs.com/2016/07/03/upgrading-rails-5-controller-tests/. The suggestion is to access the controller method that would set the appropriate session value for you. This comment shows and example of how you might work around this limitation: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23386#issuecomment-192954569

```
  # helper method
  def sign_in_as(name)
    post login_url, params: { sig: users(name).perishable_signature )
  end

class SomeControllerTest
  setup { sign_in_as 'david' }

  test 'the truth' do
  ..
```

Answer (score 2):

Try set `session` through `open_session` method

```
open_session do |sess|
  sess.get "/login", user_id: users(:stephen).id
  assert_redirected_to root_url, 'Expected redirect to root'
end
```

Comment: `params != session`

Comment: @stephenmurdoch I've refreshed my answer, could you try it

Comment: Thanks @itsnikolay it looks like there is a bug in Rails which my answer explains a bit more about.

Comment: This answer is incorrect for rails 5, the open_session method is no longer available: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25394

Comment: It's work is Rails 6 https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Integration/Runner.html#method-i-create_session

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that controller tests now inherit from `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` by default and the code that [handles the behaviour I wanted](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb#L462) sits in `ActionController::TestCase`.

So the fix for now is to do the following:

1 - modify your controller test to inherit from ActionController::TestCase

```
class SessionsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
```

2 - modify all of your http request calls to use symbolized action names instead of urls:

```
# so change this
get login_url

# to this
get :new
```

And then you should be able to use the new `kw_args` in your requests like so:

```
# now this will work fine
get :new, session: { user_id: user.id }

# and so will this
session[:user_id] = user.id
```

I'm going to open an issue on github later on as I imagine this behaviour is not intended. Thanks to @BoraMa for leading me to the answer

Answer (score -3):

I think you can do as this:

```
delete cart_url(@cart), params: { 'session' => { :cart_id => @cart.id }}
```