# How to use session in the test controller in rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, testing

*Agile Web Development With Rails4* gives an example test code like this:

*carts_controller_test.rb*:

```
test "should destroy cart" do
  assert_difference('Cart.count', -1) do
    session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
    ...
```

However, when I try this in rails 5

```
>>rake test
```

an error is raised

> NoMethodError: undefined method `session' for
>   nil:NilClass

How to use session in the test controller in rails 5? Or did I overlook some important config?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Did you run it under rails 5? This code does fail with rails 5.

Comment: @RobinClowers: honestly, don't remember. I'm gonna withdraw my comment.

Answer (score 8):

In Rails 5 it is no longer possible to access session in controller tests: http://blog.napcs.com/2016/07/03/upgrading-rails-5-controller-tests/. The suggestion is to access the controller method that would set the appropriate session value for you. This comment shows and example of how you might work around this limitation: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23386#issuecomment-192954569

```
  # helper method
  def sign_in_as(name)
    post login_url, params: { sig: users(name).perishable_signature )
  end

class SomeControllerTest
  setup { sign_in_as 'david' }

  test 'the truth' do
  ..
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer in the  [Unable to set session hash in Rails 5 controller test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796129/unable-to-set-session-hash-in-rails-5-controller-test)

Test controllers of rails5 inherit from ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest by default  while rails4 from ActionController::TestCase. Session is not available in the context of ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest.

Answer (score -5):

The following code works:

```
delete cart_url(@cart), params: { 'session' => { :cart_id => @cart.id }}
```